# mp4 video doesn't play on Safari

Tags: safari, mp4, video.js

My frontend (React, videojs 7.20.1):

```
const playFunc = ()=> {
            if (!player.src.src) {
                player.src({
                    src: "http://192.168.0.86:8080/api/v1/" + "get-video/" + videoId,
                    type: "video/mp4"
                });
            }
            player.play();
        };
```

My backend (java 8):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get-video/{video-id}", produces = "video/mp4")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getVideo(@PathVariable("video-id") String videoId) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "HLC_Promo_-Small.mp4";
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("video/mp4"))
                .body(os -> os.write(bytes/*videoService.getVideo(videoId).getContent()*/));
    }
```

I take data from a file in this example. It works for Chrome and Android Chrome, video plays. But not for Safari. This file also plays on QuickTime. And the file plays on Safari, if I drag and drop it on Safari. Please help me.

Comment: Whether a video file opens in QuickTime, or by opening it directly as a file in Safari is largely irrelevant, there are stricter requirements when playing in an HTML5 video element in general and Safari can be especially picky. Check whether the server is setting a content-type header correctly and supports range requests.

Comment: @misterben Thank you for your answer. I knew that I don't know something and "supports range requests" let me google an example of code that works perfectly for both browsers.